# One Email-to-case should assign to 2 queues

Tags: process-builder, case, email2case, queue, assignment-rules

We have  setup one email-to-case and the cases are assigning to one queue....but we have a new requirement came up. If the same email-to-case subject has 'Electronic' then it should be assigned to different queue ...how can we do this?

Comment: welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. This site works best when you've done some work and have a specific problem to overcome related to that work. Your question, as asked, is really just asking for someone to do your requirement. You can [edit] your question to provide more on what you've done or researched to solve this requirement, and where you may be stuck in implementing anything (ex. flow to assign to queue after case is created).

Answer (score 3):

Email-to-case always runs Case Assignment rules so all you need is an assignment rule that inspects Subject using Contains operator for `Electronic` and assign to the new queue.

Note that a case can only have one owner at a time so it can’t be in two queues at once

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to have a case assigned to two different queue at a same time then that is not possible.

If requirement is basis certain keywords and assigning it to some specific queue then it shall be pretty straight forward, you just need to set the owner of a case as a required queue basis the keyword availability.

Comment: Thanks for your response . Our business team wants these E2C to be assigned to two different queues when case is created through E2C ........ 1. subject contains 'Electronic' then assign to 'A' queue , subject with no 'Electronic' then assign to 'B' queue.